# How to use a conditional to evaluate a paired variable in case statement

Tags: sql, group-by, conditional-statements, case, ssms

I'm working with a dataset (in SSMS) that looks something like this:

| CaseID | State | EventTimeStamp | Cleared |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | OrderReceived | 2024-03-20 | 0 |
| 1 | Completed | 2024-03-21 | 0 |
| 1 | Completed | 2024-03-22 | 1 |
| 2 | OrderReceived | 2024-03-24 | 0 |
| 2 | Completed | 2024-03-25 | 0 |
| 2 | Completed | 2024-03-26 | 1 |
| 2 | Completed | 2024-03-27 | 0 |
| 3 | OrderReceived | 2024-03-28 | 0 |
| 3 | OrderReceived | 2024-03-29 | 1 |
| 3 | Completed | 2024-03-31 | 0 |

EDIT FOR CONTEXT:
The actual dataset has ~40 States, but I'd like to track about 25. Some states REQUIRE other states to be marked done, but others don't and some can be in progress simultaneously. Any state can have an event Clear = 1, but it would require a Clear = 0 event first i.e. an event that didn't happen can't be cleared. Events for any state will happen in 0, 1, 0,... Cleared order every single time.

For the purpose of this dummy dataset the MAX(EventTimeStamp) for an OrderReceived could be Cleared = 1, and the MAX(EventTimeStamp) for the Completed event for the same CaseID could be Cleared = 0. There is also potential for a case to have MAX(EventTimeStamp) for OrderReceived to be NULL and MAX(EventTimeStamp) for Completed to have a value. Additionally, it is possible for MAX(EventTimeStamp) for OrderReceived to be AFTER MAX(EventTimeStamp) for Completed. In that case the desired result would simply look like

| CaseID | OrderReceived | Completed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 2024-03-20 | 2024-03-18 |

In that case the last EventTimeStamp would display for each. The engineer who made the database made didn't hardcode a lot of restrictions because a lot of changes are still being made to the workflow.

```
CREATE TABLE CaseTracking 
(
    [CaseID]    bigint,
    [State]     VARCHAR(512),
    [EventTimeStamp]    date,
    [Cleared]   bit
);

INSERT INTO CaseTracking ([CaseID], [State], EventTimeStamp, Cleared) VALUES
    ('1', 'OrderReceived', '2024-03-20', '0'),
    ('1', 'Completed', '2024-03-21', '0'),
    ('1', 'Completed', '2024-03-22', '1'),
    ('2', 'OrderReceived', '2024-03-24', '0'),
    ('2', 'Completed', '2024-03-25', '0'),
    ('2', 'Completed', '2024-03-26', '1'),
    ('2', 'Completed', '2024-03-27', '0'),
    ('3', 'OrderReceived', '2024-03-28', '0'),
    ('3', 'OrderReceived', '2024-03-29', '1'),
    ('3', 'Completed', '2024-03-31', '0');

SELECT * FROM CaseTracking
```

I'd like to take a look at how long it takes between certain states and so I organized the table by column State using "group by". I was hoping to make a table that evaluated the MAX(EventTimeStamp) for each state, but if Cleared = 1 then the value would return NULL instead. The desired result would look like this. For this database, states can be cleared and it's recorded the same as any other event, but with Cleared = 1. If the MAX(TimeEventStamp) has a Cleared = 1 value that means it still needs to be done which is why I'd like a NULL return. The value for CaseID = 2 Completed is 2024-3-27 since I'd want the value associated with the MAX(EventTimeStamp). If Cleared happens in 0, 1, 0 order I'd like the timestamp of the last 0. If Cleared happens in 0, 1, 0, 1 order I'd like a NULL return

| CaseID | OrderReceived | Completed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-03-20 | NULL |
| 2 | 2024-03-24 | 2024-03-27 |
| 3 | NULL | 2024-03-31 |

I've been playing around in https://dbfiddle.uk/JG38HeOH

I tried an AND conditional within the CASE clause, but ran into an issue where instead of returning the NULL I want for CaseID = 1, I instead get the MAX(TimeEventStamp) for any time the conditions are met

```
SELECT CaseID 
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN State = 'OrderReceived' AND Cleared = 0 THEN EventTimeStamp 
            ELSE NULL END) AS OrderReceived
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN State = 'Completed' AND Cleared = 0 THEN EventTimeStamp 
            ELSE NULL END) AS Completed

FROM CaseTracking
GROUP BY CaseID
```

Results look like this

| CaseID | OrderReceived | Completed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-03-20 | 2024-03-21 |
| 2 | 2024-03-24 | 2024-03-27 |

Comment: First of all, you should pay much more attention to the data types you use. In your fiddle, all your columns are of type varchar which is incorrect. I hope this is some copy-paste issue in your fiddle only, not also wrong in your DB? But by the way, thank you for creating a fiddle, that's quite useful and lot of people don't do so!

Comment: yes this is specific to the fiddle; sorry

Comment: Please explain in detail why Completed should be NULL for CaseID 1

Comment: I added an edit for more context; In the original dataset there is a record for every event. An event can be either a Cleared = 0 or Cleared = 1. For this dataset Cleared = 0 means that this event was successfully done and Cleared = 1 means that even though at one point this state was successfully done, it was manually cleared and therefore needs to be addressed again. If the MAX(TimeEventStamp) of the event has a Cleared = 1 that means that it still is pending. At that point in time it still needs to be done and should be Marked Done in the future

Comment: Should `OrderReceived` also be NULL if  `Cleared = '1'`? Is there always a `OrderReceived` row for each case?

Comment: Yes and yes. Any state type can have a record where the MAX(EventTimeStamp) has a Cleared = 1 value and therefore return NULL

Comment: To clarify, Cleared = 1 only matters if it's attached to the MAX(EventTimeStamp). If the latest OrderReceived event has a Cleared = 1 then yes it should return NULL. If there happens to be three OrderReceived events and they happen in Cleared = 0, 1, 0 order, then ideally the SQL query should return the EventTimeStamp for the last Cleared = 0 event

Comment: Can there be more than one OrderReceived? If so, does only the latest count? If so, what happens if the latest OrderReceived is after the latest Completed? Please give a ***full*** description of what can and can not happen to these events, and how to treat them in ***all*** cases (edit your question and add the details there, comments are not the appropriate place).

Comment: @MatBailie Yes. Each State can have both Cleared 0 and Cleared 1 rows. Although OP doesn't give an example for OrderReceived having a null result, the same logic applies to both state types.

Comment: @Bohemian That doesn't answer my last question, and doesn't put the details where they belong (in the question, not comments)

Comment: @medusa_apologist add an example to your question of when OrderReceived should be null, like I did for [my answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78233205/256196) [demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/iD18h3ac)

Comment: You still haven't clarified what ***should happen*** if the latest Received is after the latest Completed.

Comment: @MatBailie Yes you're right. I got turned around while adding context and data

Comment: @MatBailie added what should happen if latest Received is after Completed. I'm sorry for the disjointed information; new here and I'm thankful for the feedback

Comment: Please upvote / accept answers that helped you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets the latest row for each state of each case, then pivots the rows to one row per case.

```
WITH
  sorted AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER()
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY CaseID, State
            ORDER BY EventTimeStamp DESC
      )
        AS row_id
  FROM
    CaseTracking
)
SELECT
  CaseID,
  MAX(CASE WHEN State = 'OrderReceived' THEN EventTimeStamp END) AS OrderReceived,
  MAX(CASE WHEN State = 'Completed'     THEN EventTimeStamp END) AS Completed
FROM
  sorted
WHERE
  row_id = 1
  AND
  Cleared = 0
GROUP BY
  CaseID
```

| CaseID | OrderReceived | Completed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-03-20 | *null* |
| 2 | 2024-03-24 | 2024-03-27 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hN_gXTPq)

Comment: This is a cute trick, but I would expect a join to be faster than windowing function.  Can't use hashes on windowing functions, so this would be O(2n) vs O(n)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in one pass over the table; you must self join for each type of State.

Use a CTE to find the last `EventTimeStamp` for each State and apply that to each join.

```
WITH last AS (
  SELECT
    CaseID,
    State,
    MAX(EventTimeStamp) as EventTimeStamp
  FROM CaseTracking
  GROUP BY CaseID, State
)
SELECT
  i.CaseID,
  CASE WHEN c1.Cleared = 0 THEN c1.EventTimeStamp END AS OrderReceived,
  CASE WHEN c2.Cleared = 0 THEN c2.EventTimeStamp END AS Completed
FROM last i
LEFT JOIN last o ON o.CaseID = i.CaseID
  AND o.State = 'OrderReceived'
LEFT JOIN CaseTracking c1 ON c1.CaseID = i.CaseID
  AND c1.State = o.State
  AND c1.EventTimeStamp = o.EventTimeStamp
LEFT JOIN last c ON c.CaseID = i.CaseID
  AND c.State = 'Completed'
LEFT JOIN CaseTracking c2 ON c2.CaseID = c1.CaseID
  AND c2.State = c.State
  AND c2.EventTimeStamp = c.EventTimeStamp
WHERE i.State = 'OrderReceived'
```

See [live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/iD18h3ac), showing logic working with OrderReceived too.

This query can be extended to work with as many other column as needed by copying the pattern.

Comment: It seems to be possible to do without any self joins [to me...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78233219/53341)

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: There is some discussion about there be multiple created events.  If this is true then the following answer needs to be updated.**

We can take the dataset and get the data for the max and the min like this

```
SELECT CaseID, Min(EventTimeStamp) as MinTS, Max(EventTimeStamp) as MaxTS
FROM CaseTracking 
GROUP BY CaseID
```

Now we need to join back to get the data for the max item

```
SELECT grouped.CaseID, grouped.MinTS as OrderRecieved,
       CASE WHEN last.Cleared = 1 THEN NULL ELSE last.EventTimeStamp END AS Completed
FROM (
  SELECT CaseID, Min(EventTimeStamp) as MinTS, Max(EventTimeStamp) as MaxTS
  FROM CaseTracking 
  GROUP BY CaseID
) AS grouped
LEFT JOIN CaseTracking AS last ON grouped.CaseID = last.CaseID AND grouped.MaxTS = last.EventTimeStamp
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/KtXt7c6T

Comment: They don't seem to necessarily want the first and last row. If OrderReceived happens multiple times, they want the latest row for that state; last row per event state. (Details are hidden in the comments, unhelpfully.)

Comment: @MatBailie -- that is what I'm doing, first is the same as Min(EventTimeStamp) and I join on just the Max(EventTimeStamp) see linked fiddle.

Comment: I'm saying that minTS does not match what they say in the comments; `If there happens to be three OrderReceived events and they happen in Cleared = 0, 1, 0 order, then ideally the SQL query should return the EventTimeStamp for the LAST Cleared = 0 event`

Comment: @MatBailie -- the data and comments suggest there are only multiple for OrderRecieved events.

Comment: @MatBailie no. If the last OrderReceived row is cleared 1, OrderReceived should be null. The same logic needs to be applied to both Completed and OrderReceived

Comment: @hogan You can't argue that my quote is wrong, as I quoted the OP (This is why I hate users not pushing OP's to keep clarification in the question itself)

Comment: @MatBailie -- you are talking about MinTS -- MinTS is never a received order, it is always a created order.  I don't fault your comment just that it has to do with the other thing (creating not receiving)

Comment: @MatBailie -- MaxTS will always have the most recent even (which is received, multiple) and then checks for the bit to see if it should be null.

Comment: In the Op's data, and your demo, OrderReceived corresponds to minTS ***(Received and Completed, not Created and Received)***

Comment: @MatBailie -- exactly :)  -- I added a note pending updates from the OP

Comment: Received and Completed, ***not*** Created and Received...